# Returning object with different value

Tags: dictionary, f#, sequence, linqpad

Is there a way to return an object used in a lambda expression, but with a different value? I've been using the "kind of linq-select" way, but I'd like to do something like this:

```
let bob= tab 
|> Seq.map (fun x -> ignore (x.Value=x.Value+1); x)
|> Seq.iter (fun x -> x.Dump())
```

making all the `x`'s in my sequence to have their value +1'ed.

instead of doing this:

```
let bob= tab 
|> Seq.map (fun x -> Ville(IdVille= 9, NoVille=x.Value+1, Nom=x.Nom, __RowVersion = x.__RowVersion))
|> Seq.iter (fun x -> x.Dump())
```

edit:

What I expect to get : from this, a dump of the sequence, hence the Iter and Dump...
What I want the sequence to be? Here is an example, well the original sequence, but after applying a function to each element and get a copy of the result... (No side effect on the original sequence).

For example, I have a sequence of names, I'd like to have a copy of the original sequence, but with upper-cased names. Now imagine the same, but with a sequence of objects got from a database.

Edit2:

I made a test with LinqPad and AdventureWorks database, and I did this:

```
let dc = new TypedDataContext()

let tab = dc.GetTable<Address>()

let bob = tab 
        |> Seq.map (fun x -> ignore (x.AddressLine1 <- "Bob"); x) 

tab.Dump()
bob.Dump()
```

The 2 Dump() results are differents.  If I invert the 2 Dump() calls, both results are the same. You were right!

Comment: If you want the original sequence unchanged then copying the objects is your only choice.

Comment: `ignore (x.Value=x.Value+1)` means `ignore false` which does nothing. Remember to use `<-` for assignment.

Comment: @Guvante Thanks, changing the `=` by `<-` did it. And the original sequence doesn't get changed! As wanted! Can you post this as an answer please?

Comment: @Pacane: See my edit. The original sequence _is_ changed.

Comment: +1 for showing how good Linqpad is for testing this kind of thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to tell what you're trying to do, but mutating a value suggests an imperative approach, so why not a `for` loop?

```
for x in tab do
  x.Value <- x.Value + 1
  x.Dump()
```

What value do you expect for `bob`? `Seq.iter` returns `unit`. If you mutate `tab` within `Seq.map` it will have the same value as `bob`.

EDIT

If you modify elements of a sequence within `map` the result and the original sequence will be one and the same. `map` is not intended to be used with side effects. An example:

```
type T(value) =
  member val Value = value with get, set

let tab = [T(0); T(1); T(3)]
let bob = tab |> Seq.map (fun x -> x.Value <- x.Value + 1; x)
tab = (Seq.toList bob) //true
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `map` along with an object expression to update just one field:

```
let bob = tab 
|> Seq.map (fun x -> {x with Value = x.Value + 1})
|> Seq.iter (fun x -> x.Dump())
```

Though `bob` will not get the results of `Dump()` assigned to it if you are using `iter`.  You'd need to use `map` again for that.

**Edit**

This only works with [record types.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233184.aspx)

Comment: Why? Seq.Iter would use the result of the Seq.Map wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, `iter` will take input from the previous `map`.  But then you call `Dump()` inside of `iter` and that gets ignored.

Comment: I tried your solution, and unfortunately since I'm fetching from a database it seems that the `with Value` isn't recognized for my type. (Which is not declared explicitly anywhere...)

Comment: But I'm sure it'd have worked with explicitly declared types.